# OpenCV load/save histogram data

Tags: c++, image, opencv, histogram

Is there any way to store an OpenCv image histogram to disk so it can be loaded directly without being forced to load the image again and computing the histogram from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are working on single channel (gray scale) image, the histogram can be represent by a single channel row matrix which length is equal to the number of bins in your histogram.
Then you can easily load/save your histogram from/to a text file.
If you want to use c++ opencv api, filestorage structure is also provide. Read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=filestorage#).

Here is a simple example:

```
// save file
cv::Mat my_histogram;
cv::FileStorage fs("my_histogram_file.yml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
if (!fs.isOpened()) {std::cout << "unable to open file storage!" << std::endl; return;}
fs << "my_histogram" << my_histogram;
fs.release();

// load file
cv::Mat my_histogram;
cv::FileStorage fs("my_histogram_file.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
if (!fs.isOpened()) {std::cout << "unable to open file storage!" << std::endl; return;}
fs >> "my_histogram" >> my_histogram;
fs.release();
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I need the data into a cvHistogram to perform comparisons with it. I assume calling cv::createHist() and passing it the loaded cv::Mat will work, right?

Comment: double compareHist(InputArray H1, InputArray H2, int method) -- InputArray could be your loaded cv::Mat.

Comment: IsOpen() is depreciated. Use   if( !fs.isOpened() ){ instead.

Comment: I got an error when I tried to read it as
`fs >> "my_histogram" >> my_histogram;`
I had to change it to:
`fs["my_histogram"] >> my_histogram;`
ref: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html